# E: Unable to locate package libvpx3 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to install libvpx using the link [here](https://www.thelinuxfaq.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus/libvpx3) .

```
    $sudo apt-get install libvpx3
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package libvpx3
```

My ubuntu details are below -

```
    $lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
    Release:        18.04
    Codename:       bionic
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: That library is only available for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libvpx3 ).  The link you provided was for 17.04 which is EOL thus doesn't show in the package reports anymore. I would try and solve your issue another way (ie. alternate that doesn't require that lib) or you could check all deps & direct download it and install it (*not an ideal solution as could create issues down the line with upgrades etc*)

Comment: It's libvpx5 in 18.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libvpx3 has been updated to libvpx5 (VP8 and VP9 video codec shared libraries) in Ubuntu 18.04 and later. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libvpx5
```

VP8 and VP9 are open video codecs, originally developed by On2 and released as open source by Google. They are the successor of the VP3 codec, on which the Theora codec was based.